# WCF Transactions: WSAtomicTransactionOctober2004 vs. WSAtomicTransaction11

Tags: wcf, transactions, distributed-transactions, wsat

WCF has three transaction protocols: OleTransactions, WSAtomicTransactionOctober2004 & WSAtomicTransaction11

OleTransactions are the Windows specific OleTx protocol, but both the other two are just listed as the implementation of the WSAT protocol.

So there must be a difference between the 2004 & 11 options?

Only thing I can GUESS is

- 2004 = [November 2004 spec](http://specs.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/10/wsat/wsat1104.pdf)
- 11 = [August 2005 spec](http://specs.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/10/wsat/wsat.pdf) (seems odd, since this is version 1.0 and the name implies 1.1)

Answer (score 3):

For .net <=3.0, use WSAtomicTransactionOctober2004
If you use COM+, use OleTransactions
otherwise, use WSAtomicTransaction11

Comment: So you saying the only difference between 2004 & 11 is that 2004 was supported in .NET 3.0 and 11 was added in 11? Seems silly to have just that difference, so what are the differences between the two?

Comment: All I can say is where I use(d) them - this was also backed up in some 70-513 revision guides I've used too. The exact differences - I'm not too sure sorry. Nor is google, by the looks.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between the three types can be summed up as follows

**WSAtomicTransactionOctober2004**

- Support for version 3.0 of the Microsoft.Net framework.

**WSAtomicTransaction11**

- Standard for **HTTP** transactions.
- **Required** for transactions to Web services built on third-party technologies.
- Can be used where the server and client are written using WCF and using **TCP** or **named pipes** but it is not the preferred method.

**OleTransaction**

- Standard for **TCP** and **named pipe** transactions where the server and client are written using WCF.
- To use COM+ transactions that use RPC and DTC.
- **Can't be used** for transactions to Web services built on third-party technologies.
- **Can't be used** with **HTTP**.

Comment: THanks for the answer but same point as I had with @chris answer: So you saying the only difference between 2004 & 11 is that 2004 was supported in .NET 3.0 and 11 was added in 11? Seems silly to have just that difference, so what are the differences between the two?

Comment: @RobertMacLean - First thing that came to mind and kind of confirmed from the links you've provided is that `WSAtomicTransactionOctober2004` only supports `SOAP 1.1` while `WSAtomicTransaction11` also supports `SOAP 1.2`. Note that I am in the process of learning WCF myself so you should take this with a serious grain of salt.